# wget alternative in curl

Tags: linux, curl, command-line, wget, api-key

I am using wget on linux system like :

```
 wget -r -nH --cut-dirs=3 --user="username" --password="password" --no-parent https://artifactory.company.com/nestetedlink1/nested_link2/directory_to_download -P home/user
```

Using this I get only files saved in the path no unwanted directory component from url: `home/user/file_1, file_2`

Is this possible to do the same functionality using curl command?
if I have to stick with WGET how to pass the api key I tried the below with --header='X-Auth-Token:, am I doing something wrong :

```
 wget -r -nH --cut-dirs=3 --header='X-Auth-Token: <api_key>' --no-parent https://artifactory.company.com/nestetedlink1/nested_link2/directory_to_download -P home/user
```

How to insert api Key instead of username and password in wget?

Answer (score 0):

```
wget --header='X-JFrog-Art-Api:api-key' https://artifactoryurl/filename.gz
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?